# Does 2013 Fit LX 5-door have pouch behind passenger front seat?

Tags: honda, fit

I recently got my car back after extensive flood remediation.  The seats were removed, rug replaced, and electrical system replaced.  Most things seem fine except when I put stuff back into the car, there seems to be a storage pouch missing behind the passenger front seat.  Since the remediation took almost 1.5 months (I actually forgot how to drive stick in that time), and I've owned other cars before, I can't be quite sure whether the pouch was there before.  However, I'm somewhat certain that the thing I was putting back belonged in a pouch back there (not that it matters, but it is a folded reflective foil-lined blanket for emergencies).

Can anyone please confirm whether the subject car model has a storage pouch behind the front passenger seat?  In case it matters, I'm in Ontario, Canada.